# When does "looking for a script" become too localized?

Tags: discussion, looking-for-a-script

Some questions where users are looking for scripts have very long feature sets that are very specific. I don't see how it would benefit anyone but the question-asker in their specific situation. Here is [an example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24147/does-such-a-php-script-exists).

I am thinking that questions like this, when tagged [looking-for-a-script](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looking-for-a-script), should be closed as too localized. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how long the feature set is. If someone says "I want a CMS with a photo gallery and a forum" then we could either point them to such a thing, or http://cmsmatrix.org/.

However this particular feature set is quite long, with some quite specialised stuff, and I think it unlikely that anyone will know the answer off the top of their head and the questioner would be better off doing their own homework.

Comment: There will definitely will be some subjectivity involved. Our 3000+ rep users will need to vote to close or leave comments to help flush these out.

Comment: +1 [I was the unexplained downvote; walked away while trying to come up with something that wouldn't sound like berating.] Those requested features went *way* into "do my research for me" territory. The standards(Joomla, WordPress, Drupal) could likely all handle this via their ecosystems, and a real response would require a long list naming *specific plugins* for the various feature implementations requested. In isolation some of those might be valid questions, but en masse like this, it becomes of extremely limited application for later visitors.